# Is Fiddler an ascendant or is his deck just something special?

Tags: malazan

I've just re-read the "reading" of the Decks of Dragons by Fiddler in Letheras (in Dust of Dreams):

> The cards forcefully pin the attendants to the walls, breaking some ribs and other bones. Throughout the city some power is felt by the elder gods like Mael and the Errant. Two gods helping Mael protect Seren even just burn and melt.

So either he has some power over the deck or the deck itself is more powerful than others we've seen.

> Later on it is written that Fiddler managed to hold a few cards back.

So it seems it is Fiddler who can restrain the deck if he wants to. Which begs the question: Is he just another ascendant (who maybe even doesn't know it) or why are his readings so powerful?

Comment: The entire bridgeburnners are some form of ascended some at higher stages then others

Comment: @Himarm But as far as I understood it, only the ones who "died", like Whiskeyjack and Hedge before he came back to "live". Though Fiddler was responsible for the ascending with his visit to this Tanno Spiritwalker.

Comment: its weird but from what i understood the bridgeburners still "alive" are in some pre-stage or half level. its pretty much for sure that when fiddler dies hell join with the rest of the bridge burners at least from what i understood. magic and ascendancy dont really follow preset rules, and being "ascended" can have various strengths behind it.

Comment: It's too late for me now - I'm trying not to read anything else on this page! - but is it possible to reword this question to make it less of a spoiler?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Hm, I put everything important into spoiler tags and if you read anything after the first line of my question, it's honestly your fault.  Or what about the question and the first sentence spoils anything?

Comment: @KutuluMike I know that Letheras is special with a few resident Elder gods. And what Icarium did also probably plays its part, but still, also earlier readings from Fiddler were a bit special, just not as violent as this one.